# Как импортировать профиль публикации Azure Web App в Консольный проект в VS?

Tags: visual-studio, azure

Есть Azure Web App, который будет использоваться как размещение ClickOnce дистрибутива консольного приложения.
Есть профиль публикации, загруженный из этого Web App.

Как импортировать этот профиль в студию? Сейчас руками вношу урл'ы публикации и установки, логин и пароль.
Или хотя бы заставить студию сохранить этот пароль.

Уточняю. Просто паблиш в веб-службу, **не как WebJob**.

Comment: Что-то как-то не понятно вопрос поставлен... Зачем вам профиль публикации портировать в студию? Просто установите Azure SDK и сможете паблишить ваши веб-приложения в Azure App Services по правой кнопке мыши по проекту.

Comment: Импорт выгруженного из Azure профиля нужен, чтобы не вводить каждый раз, как минимум, учетные данные. При публикации в Azure проекта как WebJob такая возможность есть. При публикации дистрибутива ClickOnce в виртуальную машину в Azure приходиться вводить всё руками в мастере.

Comment: Так погоди... Ты в Web App деплоишь или в виртуалку???

Comment: Публикация ClickOnce дистрибутива приложения в  Web App. Всё точно, как написано в исходном вопросе.